# My coding line img/png keeps changing

Tags: html, css

I created a some HTML but the code keeps changing and I don't know why.

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://i.imgur.com/at2rsbu.png?1"/>
```

Here is a [screenshot of what I meant](http:////imgur.com/c3ZdH28). It might be easier to understand.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. If there is already something like this on Stack Overflow please provide the link as I couldn't find it.

Comment: Image is too small to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `type='image/x-icon'` instead of `type='image/png'` and try giving the image a path instead of a URL.

Comment: @mastkilxp: if this worked, please click the tick mark to the left, to 'accept' the answer and mark it as the correct one. This is how we thank people on Stack Overflow. Thanks!